# Bootstrap container class partially responsive

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing an asp.net application that is using Bootstrap. I am running into a problem with the container class. What I am trying to do is have a grid consisting of 3 labels and 3 drop downs. Here is the code for that:

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body container">
                <div class="cssFilterGrid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:Label ID="label 1" runat="server" Text="label 1" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:Label ID="label 2" runat="server" Text="label 2" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:Label ID="label 3" runat="server" Text="label 3" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" CssClass="form-control" DataTextField="ddl1" runat="server" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" CssClass="form-control" DataTextField="StatusString" DataValueField="ddl2" runat="server" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" CssClass="form-control" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="ddl3" runat="server" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 filterBtn">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Filter" OnClick="btnFilter_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the cssFilterGrid is as follows:

```
.cssFilterGrid
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

With the container class on the panel-body div, the grid is responsive 90% of the time. However, at some resolutions, dropdown #3 goes off the screen. If I remove the container class, the grid is responsive 100% of the time. Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching to container-fluid instead of container...

The container has one fixed width for each screen size in bootstrap (xs,sm,md,lg); .container-fluid expands to fill the available width. i.e. Depending on the width of the viewport that the webpage is being viewed on, the container class gives its div a specific fixed width.

Comment: Yes, setting to container-fluid works just fine. I would like the labels and dropdown lists to be close together. With container-fluid, they are too large and have too much space between them.

Comment: you can use different sized columns (like xs or sm) to make things closer together.. have a look here: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/